# Do I have to define a rule or a query to get the name of the instance from the ontology (in a variable)?

Tags: java, ontology, jess

My instances have names [(screenshot of the said names in Protégé)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSeYX.png) and slots [(image here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bU8ke.png).

What I need to do is: knowing the value of the slot "DESCRIPTION", getting the name of the instance so I can use it in my Java program.

I thought of a `defrule`, but does it allow me to have the result in a global variable? Can you please guide me in doing this?

Comment: What's the point of having those instances unless you are going to write rules? Why do you need a slot value in a Java program as you are about to develop a Jess/Protégé program? Not that it cannot be done but it'll complicate matters somewhat if you do a bit here and a bit there.

Comment: I am developing a Java application with Jess. I just use some JessTab commands for quick operations as the file I'm working with is .pprj, other than that, I use Protégé only to visualise my ontology. As for the instance, I need to use it as a String in the Java code. The slot value "DESCRIPTION" is chosen by the user of the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed use a rule in combination with a global:

```
(defglobal ?*desc* = "")
```

Write a rule:

```
(defrule getDescription
    (SystemEauDeRefroidissement
       (http..#description ?d))
=>
    (bind ?*desc* ?d))
```

This might work if you have only a single instance of `SystemEauDeRefroidissement`. You can retrieve the global's value using the Jess API:

```
Context ctxt = rete.getContext();
Variable var = ctxt.getVariable( "desc" );
String desc = var.stringValue( ctxt );
```

I haven't tested any of this.

**Edit** If you have the description, you may write a rule (now more in the Protégé style:

```
(object
   (is-a http..#SystemEauDeRefroidissement) 
   (OBJECT ?sedr)
   (http..#description ...)
=>
    (bind ?*sedr* ?sedr))
```

I don't know how you'd like to insert the description value into the Jess environment, so that's why there's the ellipsis.

Comment: Thank you for helping, but I think I didn't explain it well. The description is known and already in a variable. I want to use it to get the name of the instance. (For example I would use the description "VanneDeRegularisaton..." to get the result "00B_Instance_1"). In my imaginary language it is something like `get instance-name where DESCRIPTION = "VanneDeRegularisation.."`
But I sincerely thank you for your answer.

Comment: There's no such thing as an "instance-name". If you need the instance where a slot has a certain value, you need to write a rule or a query.